# Can we access BIOS setting of windows EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, android-emulator

OS: windows 10

[image]

when I am trying to run the emulator from android studio it is displaying following error:

**Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1**

I am trying to fix that by running following exe:
C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm-android.exe

When I am trying to run this getting following error:

[image]

The solution which I found in internet is enable ' Virtual Technology' in BIOS. 
But I am not getting any option to do it in windows EC2 instance.

Can someone please help to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: Have you just considered using AWS Device Farm, which is made for testing android apps?  https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/

Comment: ANd I'd be shocked if you could access BIOS.  Those are hardware settings for the entire machine.  You rarely get the entire machine, and which machine you get changes frequently on AWS.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't enable Virtualization, since you're currently inside a virtual machine. Your EC2 instance isn't using an entire server; it's a VM, or possibly a container, running alongside many others on one physical machine.

Comment: @GabeSechan: I am not able to access the BIOS setting in EC2 instance also i don't know weather we can access it not not , let me try with android testing apps, thanks for looking in to it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it isn't possible to access the BIOS when booting an EC2 instance.

Hope this will help you

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=146768

Answer (score -3):

in this situation you have to enter in Bios setting

so using press  f11 or Esc key go into Bios setting

in Bios find Hyper-v or Vt-x option

in Bios the Hyper-v is desabled so please you have to enabled this option  and restart the computer 
i think it's work

Comment: This isn't possible on an EC2 instance.